# Slicing a Pandas Dataframe Using Two Strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I have a large dataframe. I want to select the data that is for Machine1 and for NorthAmerica. So if Machine1 and NorthAmerica is in a row of data, I want to keep the row.

I know how to do it with one requirement:

```
df = df[df['MachineNumber'].isin(['Machine1'])]
```

Works perfectly and slices all the data I need. However, I don't know how to do this for two things.

I tried doing it twice, separately like so:

```
df = df[df['MachineNumber'].isin(['Machine1'])]
df = df[df['Region'].isin(['NorthAmerica'])]
```

and I also tried

`df = df[(df['Region']=='NorthAmerica') & (df['MachineNumber']=='Machine1')]`

but both attempts throw the error `TypeError: unsupported type for add operation` and it's returning an Empty Dataframe with only the column names. I also looked at solutions online, but they focus on the second solution but with numbers and not strings. How can I do this properly?

An example dataframe input is a csv called sortingdata.csv with two columns:

```
Region  MachineNumber
EU  Machine1
EU  Machine1
EU  Machine1
EU  Machine1
EU  Machine1
EU  Machine1
EU  Machine1
EU  Machine1
EU  Machine2
NA  Machine2
NA  Machine2
NA  Machine2
NA  Machine2
EMEA    Machine2
NA  Machine2
NA  Machine2
NA  Machine1
NA  Machine1
NA  Machine1
NA  Machine1
NA  Machine1
NA  Machine1
NA  Machine1
NA  Machine1
NA  Machine1
```

and code is

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('sortingdata.csv') 

df = df[(df['Region']=='NorthAmerica') & (df['MachineNumber']=='Machine1')]
```

It runs fine but prints and Empty DataFrame in this case.

Comment: Can you upload a sample data file to reproduce the error? `df = df[(df['Region']=='NorthAmerica') & (df['MachineNumber']=='Machine1')]` looks reasonable to me.

Comment: @JohnE It's not really a problem, because I only want to work with the df of data in NorthAmerica with Machine1, so I'm okay with overwriting it.

Comment: @JianxunLi I added sample data, you can copy paste the rows into a csv file. It is returning an empty dataframe

Comment: jenryb & @JianxunLi  -- I posted up a followup quesion to the NaN issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528621/is-this-correct-behavior-for-read-csv-and-a-data-value-of-na

Comment: @JohnE , I am having further issues with the code, but it's slightly different so I opened a new question. If you are interested it is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543959/pandas-dataframe-with-na-values-throwing-valueerror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems to work on your sample data.

```
# data
# ==================================
df

   Region MachineNumber
0      EU      Machine1
1      EU      Machine1
2      EU      Machine1
3      EU      Machine1
4      EU      Machine1
5      EU      Machine1
6      EU      Machine1
7      EU      Machine1
..    ...           ...
17     NA      Machine1
18     NA      Machine1
19     NA      Machine1
20     NA      Machine1
21     NA      Machine1
22     NA      Machine1
23     NA      Machine1
24     NA      Machine1

[25 rows x 2 columns]

# processing
# ===============================
df[(df['Region']=='NA') & (df['MachineNumber']=='Machine1')]

   Region MachineNumber
16     NA      Machine1
17     NA      Machine1
18     NA      Machine1
19     NA      Machine1
20     NA      Machine1
21     NA      Machine1
22     NA      Machine1
23     NA      Machine1
24     NA      Machine1
```

Comment: Hm. Thank you for running it through on your end... I will restart python and see if that helps!

Comment: Jian, I think I figured out the problem. For some reason, my dataframe is changing "NA" For NorthAmerica as "NaN" and that is why it is returning the empty dataframe. (I am using Python 2.7) I wonder why it is not doing it in your version.

Comment: @jenryb Uhh, I actually encounter the same problem as you did, and I convert it mannually using `df = df.fillna('NA')` to use `NA` replace all `NaNs`.

Comment: that is a helpful solution, but unfortunately there are other NA values that are actually NaNs elsewhere in the code. Here is a separate question for this problem if you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543959/pandas-dataframe-with-na-values-throwing-valueerror