# Is this correct behavior for read_csv and a data value of NA?

Tags: python, pandas

(I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10647) at GitHub.)

The following behavior doesn't seem correct to me.  It seems like if the default for `read_csv` is `na_values=False` then no values including 'NA' should be interpreted as NaN but this does not appear to be the case.

This behavior was noticed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527138/slicing-a-pandas-dataframe-using-two-strings) (see the comments to the answer by @JianxunLi), where 'NA' actually means 'North America'.  I actually am unable to find a way to read this in without having it changed to NaN and there definitely should be some way to do this.

Here's the example csv.

```
%more foo.txt
x,y
"NA",NA
"foo",foo
```

I'm including 'NA' both in quotes and outside to see if that matters, but as you can see below it doesn't seem to.

```
pd.read_csv('foo.txt')
Out[56]: 
     x    y
0  NaN  NaN
1  foo  foo

pd.read_csv('foo.txt',na_values=False)
Out[57]: 
     x    y
0  NaN  NaN
1  foo  foo

pd.read_csv('foo.txt',na_values='foo')
Out[58]: 
    x   y
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN
```

It appears that data values of 'NaN' are treated the same as 'NA'.

**Edit to add:**  I think I am understanding this better based on @Marius's answer although it doesn't really seem right to me (the default behavior, that is, not Marius's answer which does seem to be a correct explanation of what is happening).

```
na_values=False    =>   NA and NaN are treated as NaN
na_values='foo'    =>   NA, NaN, and foo are treated as NaN
```

I guess I can understand this being default behavior in a number column but it doesn't seem like this should be the default for a string column.  I also would have really struggled to figure this out from the documentation without seeing Marius's answer.

**Edit to Add (2):**

Also, for comparison, I read this into Stata and Excel and in both cased they treat 'NA' as plain text, not as NaN/missing.  Is there any other package or library that would have the same default behavior as pandas here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `keep_default_na=False`, by default any strings you include in `na_values` are just added to the standard set of NA strings, e.g. `NA`, `NaN`:

```
pd.read_csv('foo.txt', keep_default_na=False)
Out[5]: 
     x    y
0   NA   NA
1  foo  foo
```

Comment: If setting `na_values` meant that only the patterns you included were treated as NaN, then you would have to include all the default patterns like NA, NaN in the list everytime you wanted to add a custom pattern. I guess that's the reasoning behind how it's done now, you don't lose the defaults unless you explicitly ask for it.

Comment: OK, thanks, I am understanding it now although I can't say I really like this. I'll edit the question.  In particular, there are many ways to specify a missing value of which NA and NaN are just two (admittedly 2 popular ways) but it seems like this should always be the user's responsibility to specify, especially in a text column.  I don't think this should be the default in a number column either, but it at least seems safe in that case.