# Pandas Dataframe with NA values throwing ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, na

I have a dataframe in pandas that looks like this

```
df.head(2)
Out[25]: 
                                   CompanyName Region MachineType
recvd_dttm                                                    
2014-07-13 12:40:40     Company1    NA    Machine1
2014-07-13 15:31:39     Company2    NA    Machine2
```

I am first taking data in a certain date range, then trying to get data that is in the Region NA and is MachineType Machine1.

However, I keep getting this error: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 3 elements`

This code worked until I added the region column and used this line: `df = df[(df['Region']=='NA') & (df['CallType']=='Optia')]`

Because at first the data for NA (NorthAmerica) was being read in as NaN, I used `keep_default_na=False` in my read_csv command.

However, I made a pivot_table this way

```
result = df.groupby([lambda idx: idx.month, 'CompanyName']).agg(len).reset_index()
result.columns = ['Month', 'CompanyName', 'NumberCalls']

pivot_table = result.pivot(index='Month', columns='CompanyName', values='NumberCalls').fillna(0)
```

And the error is coming up at the result.columns line, though I wouldn't be surprised if perhaps the fillna(0) command is acting up, as there were other `NA` values that were actually supposed to be `NaN` , not NorthAmerica.

How do I fix the ValueError and avoid NA confusion?

Comment: Would it be better for you to simply replace all the `NaN` for something like "NorthAm". You can do this `df = df.replace(np.NaN, 'NorthAm')`

Comment: @Plug4 Yes, that would be a good tactic, however there are some actual NaN entries that I want to stay NaN. They are in a different column though, so is there a way to replace NA to NorthAm in only the Region column?

Comment: Yep! See my answer below

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about 'NA' once you've read in correctly.  Take a look at the output of `result.columns`.  The error message is just telling you that `result` has 4 columns and you're trying to replace with 3 columns.  You just need to figure out why you're losing a column you expected to be there.

Comment: @JohnE You are right! All I had to do was add 'Region' to my result.columns list. Got sidetracked by the NA issue and thought it must be that. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do to replace the `NaN` in one column only:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_clipboard()
print df

# I created a test column
           recvd_dttm CompanyName  Region MachineType  Test
2014-07-13   12:40:40    Company1     NaN    Machine1   NaN
2014-07-13   15:31:39    Company2     NaN    Machine2   NaN

df['Region'] = df['Region'].replace(np.NaN, 'NorthAm')
print df

           recvd_dttm CompanyName   Region MachineType  Test
2014-07-13   12:40:40    Company1  NorthAm    Machine1   NaN
2014-07-13   15:31:39    Company2  NorthAm    Machine2   NaN
```